# Best API/code library to build a timeline/chart

Tags: javascript, google-api, chart.js

I'm reaching out for some advice on the best API/code library to use to build an interactive timeline/chart. I have included an example image below. The idea would be that you have a key, and clickable elements along a path/line that pop up/out when interacted with.

I have a lot of experience with Google Maps API, but this is quite clearly something a little different. Would you suggest ChartJS? Or something else? Just trying to get some background/research.

Do let me know if posting this on SO was the wrong thing to do.

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Take a look at [D3J](http://d3js.org/) or [Dojo](http://dojotoolkit.org/). They are both JavaScript libraries for data-driven and data-centric front-end applications.